# Realm List View Loading Slowly

Tags: android, listview, realm

I've been using Realm on android for a couple of days now, and I'm loving it. However, of late I've noticed an issue when using a realm adapter to load data into a list view. They is a delay whenever I'm launching the activity with the listview or resuming. The delay is noticeable. It's actually disturbing the whole ux interaction. I've tried using asynchronous methods but the delay is still there. Btw, I'm only loading 15 items into the listview!
Heres my current code.

```
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    adapter = new MemosListAdapter(this, null);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                newMemoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                newMemoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
    memos = realm.where(Memo.class).equalTo("latest", true).findAllSortedAsync("date");
    memos.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Memo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Memo> element) {

            adapter.updateData(element);
            empty.setVisibility((adapter.isEmpty()) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

I cant seem to get what the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The listener will be triggered when changes to the `Memo` objects after it added. So you probably need to pass a `RealmResults` at the beginning when you init adapter.

Comment: Also, you can try running Systrace: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace.html, that will give you a more solid idea about what exactly is causing the dropped frames.

Comment: So I should not use an asynchronous query?

Comment: Opps, my bad, I thought the listener is added to Realm. Just ignore what I said before, it won't impact. Can you tell if the delay is actually the time takes by the async query?

Comment: I figured out the problem. It had nothing to do with Realm but with a settext()  method in the adapter. It seems when setting text larger than width of the textview more time is taken for automatic truncation. That has removed the delay. Thank you for your assistance.